# How to get Laravel homestead on server

Tags: laravel, server, homestead

I already have a running server and i just want to get laravel homestead on it.
All the tutorials are about how to install it on a localmachine or on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homestead is VM box, it was created to copy usual server environment for using on any local machine. You absolutely do not want to use it on your server for production.

Comment: Yes, i have done a bit more research now and i thought before that Laravel homestead is one thing, my question should have been: How to get Laravel on my server? I think that i should just copy the whole Laravel folder on my server and use it through putty or something.

Comment: You can do that, but I'd recommend some better way. You can upload all files except `/vendor` directory (use Git or SSH client like putty) and then run composer update on the server . Also, do not forget to set correct permissions on `storage` and `public` directories with `chmod -R 775 storage`, for example. Finally, make changes in your `.env` file and set a database.

Comment: Why would you not want to use it on a server? If it would even be possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Laravel Docs Homestead is intended to use only in the local development.

It is just a pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, HHVM, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.

Source : [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#introduction)

You may need to look on the [forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) which does the same on production server.

You can learn more about forge [here](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge)

Comment: Thank you Sulthan.